# Is there anyway to reload the website in browser when it is reopened

Tags: android, browser, android-webview

So my basic aim is to create a browser in android studio and I have made the default url as google.com and there is also a search bar which can be used to input any url. What I have to do is  that whenever the user closes the app, and the next the time when the app is opened, it should reload the previous site. For example if the user searches for Facebook.com and closes the app, the next time when the app is opened it should reload Facebook.com and not homepage which is Google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of webview manually every time and restore it after that by using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).
for saving the last URL user visited before exit you can do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
    mEditor.put("lastUrlVisited", mWebView.getUrl());
    mEditor.commit();
}
```

And for retrieving the data you can add these lines to onCreate() method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String tmpURL = prefs.getString("lastUrlVisited", "");
if(!tmpURL.equals("")) {
    mWebView.loadUrl(tmpURL);
}
```

or depending on your need you can do this in onResume() method each time your activity resumed:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tmpURL = prefs.getString("lastUrlVisited", "");
    if(!tmpURL.equals("")) {
        mWebView.loadUrl(tmpURL);
    }
}
```